# ../ path catch http not https issue

Tags: wordpress, http, https, mixed-content

I'm using WordPress, DNS is CloudFlare.

When I enter my site seo.whoops.com.tw, it will get mixed content, but I have used Auto SSL Rewrite by CloudFlare, also I installed real simple SSL of the plugin, but the issue still exists.

After that, I check the reason is due to the theme main CSS using ../image.jpg as path and the site is catching HTTP:// not https://, but I really don't know how to fixed it（I know I can just change path with fixed URL, but due to updated after, I don't want to.）

I just notify the theme author and they say it's not wrong, so I came here to ask someone who can give me a tip.

Thanks.

Comment: In your WP site settings, have your domains with https?

Comment: Yes, all setting is using https include .htaccess.

Comment: It seems the problem is caused by stylesheet `/wp-content/themes/easyweb/css/master-min.php?ver=2.1.9`. This stylesheet defines `.our-process-wrap`'s background image as a HTTP URL. To find the root cause, please provide corresponding code detail in `master-min.php`.

Comment: Yes, the path is like this: background-image: url(../images/search-icon.png, it should catch https:// but right now, it catch http://.

Comment: When i say settings i mean in WordPress Dashboard -> Settings -> General  then WP Address and Site Address URL.. make sure they both are https://

Comment: Yes, I know that. The setting is https, and I also put the code in .htaccess that make sure my entire site is using https.